# Users are not highlighted when they presses the like button and also doesn't show the count of likes ..in django. Can You suggest me any solution

Tags: python, html, django

registration and login page is working properly but mine like button is not working it doesn't highlight users who presses like button and also doesn't show the count of like .. I don't know why... Can somebody help me to solve this issue … it will be great help please help Thank you!

1. Views.py

   ```
     from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
     from datasecurity.models import Post
     from django.urls import reverse
     from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
     from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


     # Create your views here.
     @login_required
     def likes(request, pk):
         post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk)
         post.likes.add(request.user)
         return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('datasecurity:datasecurity', args=str(pk)))
     def datasecurity(request):
         allPosts= Post.objects.all()

         context={'allPosts': allPosts}
         def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
              stuff = get_object_or_404(Post, id = self.kwargs['pk'])
              total_likes = stuff.total_likes()
              context['total_likes'] = total_likes



         return render(request, 'datasecurity/data.html',context=context)

         def blogHome(request, slug):
              post=Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).first()
              context={"post":post}
         return render(request, "datasecurity/blogHome.html", context)
   ```

2.urls.py

```
         from django.conf.urls import url

         from . import views

         app_name = 'datasecurity'

         urlpatterns = [
                 url(r'^$', views.datasecurity, name="datasecurity"),
                 url(r'^datasecurity/(?P<slug>[^/]+)', views.blogHome, name='blogHome'),
                 url(r'^likes/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.likes, name = "likes"),

         ]
```

3. Models.py

   ```
               from django.db import models
               from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
               from django.contrib.auth.models import User
               # Create your models here.
               class Post(models.Model):
                    sno=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
                    title=models.CharField(max_length=255)
                    author=models.CharField(max_length=14)
                    slug=models.CharField(max_length=130)
                    timeStamp=models.DateTimeField(blank=True)
                    content=RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
                    img = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="dataimage/")
                    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes')

                    @property
                    def total_likes(self):
                          return self.likes.count()

                    def __str__(self):
                          return self.title + " by " + self.author
   ```
4. data.html

   ```
                <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
                <head>
                <meta
                  name="viewport"
                  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
                />

                <link
                    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900"
                    rel="stylesheet"
                  />

                 <meta charset="utf-8">
                 <title></title>
                 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
                 <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">


                   <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/datasecurity.css' %}">
                 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=PT+Sans&display=swap" 
                rel="stylesheet">
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2? 
                family=Bebas+Neue&family=PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
                <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/cover/">
                <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" 
                src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v9.0" 
                 nonce="noEcH88O"></script>
               <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" 
               src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2"></script>
             </head>
              <body>

                 <!-- End header -->
                     <div id="page-wraper">

                       <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
                      <div class="responsive-nav">
                      <div class="top-navbar">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

                  <div class="container">


                    <marquee><ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                   <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'careforallapp:base' 
                   %}">Home</a></li>


                   </ul></marquee>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </nav>
                    </div>
                    <section class="section about-me" data-section="section1">
                     <div class="container">
                      <div class="section-heading">
                    <h2>Welcome to Data Security</h2>


                     {% for post in allPosts  %}
                      <div class="line-dec"></div>
                          <span
                       >This is a Bootstrap v4.2.1 CSS Template for you. Edit and use
                       this layout for your site. Updated on 21 May 2019 for repeated main menu HTML 
                       code.</span>
                         </div>
                        <div class="left-image-post">
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                         <div class="left-image">
                        {% if post.img %}
                         <img src="{{ post.img.url }}" alt="" />
                        {% endif %}
                         </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="col-md-6">
                         <div class="right-text">
                         <h4>{{post.title}}</h4>
                         <h6>Article  by {{post.author}}</h6>
                         <h2>{{post.datetime}}</h2>

                          <p>
                           {{post.content|safe | truncatechars:280}}
                          </p>

                          <from action = "{% url 'datasecurity:likes' pk=post.pk %}" method = "POST">
                           {% csrf_token %}
                           <button type="submit" name="post_id" class="btn"> Like </button> - {{ 
                            total_likes }} likes
                          </form><br><br>

                            <div class="white-button">
                            <a href="{% url 'datasecurity:blogHome' slug=post.slug %}">Read More</a>
                            </div><br>

                            </div>

                          </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>

                          </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </section>


                  </div>
    {% endfor %}
   ```

There is no error when I debug the code .. may be it is logical error .. I really don't know .. can someone help me to find out the error
Thank you

Comment: In your opening tag for the form you have written `from` instead of `form`. Also in your redirect from the likes view you are passing arguments when the view/url really doesn't expect any.

Comment: oh god how can i miss this ... Thank you Sir ... i really messed up the code .... Now it showing me error msg : "Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are: author, content, img, likes, slug, sno, timeStamp, title  " and highlighted this line: post=get_object_or_404(Post, id=pk).

Comment: You have set a custom primary key to your post model namely sno you can write `sno=pk` or `pk=pk`, (pk is independant of whatever the primary key field is named)

Comment: ohhh .... thank you sir for your help ... i got confused with several youtube videos and i messed my code ... now i got it thanks ... now it is working.... Thanks for help ... it mean alot...